# How to create a dynamic multi-line chart in chart.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chart.js

I want to create a graph with multiple lines , the issue is that the  code overwrites the previous line-graph it creates, I am passing the x and y axis value to the code as a function call , Logically it should set the x axis just once and add data to y(data in dataset) axis inorder to have more than one lines in the graph

static code to have multiple lines in the line graph

```
var config = 
        {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],   //dates populated
                datasets: [{
                    label: "My First dataset",      //Name of reporting employee
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    data: [
                            randomScalingFactor(),  //Add Datapoints(overall rating)
                            randomScalingFactor(), 
                            randomScalingFactor(), 
                            randomScalingFactor(), 
                            randomScalingFactor(), 
                            randomScalingFactor(), 
                            randomScalingFactor()
                         ],
                    fill: false,
                    --------
                }, {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    data: [
                        randomScalingFactor(),      
                        randomScalingFactor(), 
                        randomScalingFactor(), 
                        randomScalingFactor(), 
                        randomScalingFactor(), 
                        randomScalingFactor(), 
                        randomScalingFactor()
                    ],
                }]
            },
```

Below is my code which tries to do the above work for dynamically passed data, the dynamic nature causes the issue I mentioned earlier,

```
var config = 
            {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels:col_dates,   //dates populated
                    datasets: [{
                        label:Name,     //Name of reporting employee
                        backgroundColor:'#00FFFF',
                        borderColor: '#00FFFF',
                        data:O_ratings,
                        fill: false,
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    //animation: false,
                    title:{
                        display:true,
                        text:'Ratings Chart'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',              //Populate the entire datalist here
                        intersect: false,
                    },
                    hover: {
                        mode: 'nearest',
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Dates'
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Value'
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            };




ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

I have used two arrays col_dates(sets to X Axis) and O-ratings(sets to Y Axis)

Answer (score 3):

So I don't have enough reputation points to actually comment on the question. Try removing the background color attribute. It's possible that the data from the first dataset is bigger than the second one. 
I recently completed a dynamic multiline chart using php. My chart config is given below :

```
var lineChartData = {  //chart config options
    labels : [<?php echo '"'.$labelArray.'"'; ?>],
    datasets : [<?php echo $dataString; ?>],
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, {
    type:"line",
    fill: false,
    data:lineChartData,
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip : true,
                    min: 2,
                    maxTicksLimit: 10
                }
            }]
        },
    },
    responsive:true
});
```

The `$dataString` is the variable where I am passing all the data I'm retrieving from an external url

```
$dataString = $dataString."{label : '$name','fill' : 'false', data : [$br_values], borderColor : '$color', backgroundColor : 'transparent' },";
```

Let me know if I missed anything and sorry I did not answer this question sooner, I solved this 2 days ago. For more documentation on Chart.js go [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)

Kudos